# Sort table by integer value stored in varchar field

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql, criteria

Me working in spring hibernate
I have column in my database table, that of type `VARCHAR`, but it store integer value. So if i `sort` it using `sql` or `hql` or `Criteria(Order.asc)`, all are sorting it as string. I need it to be sorted as integer value it store. Here i cannot alter my table.
Is There anyway to sort it as integer using `Criteria`
Is the only solution for me is, after reading it to some list and sort inside my service?

Edited : me using `MYSQL`

Thank you

Comment: You can convert the string to int in your database, depending of your database. For Mysql (as an example) you have `convert()` and `cast()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try casting it before sorting it. In **mysql**, something like this:

```
SELECT CAST(myVarcharField AS DECIMAL(10)) as myIntField order by myIntField;
```

or as an unsigned integer:

```
SELECT CAST(myVarcharField AS UNSIGNED) as myIntField order by myIntField;
```

cast appears to be a valid [HQL expression](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions) too.

Comment: This query looks like native sql, is this possible in HQL or Criteria too?

Comment: It is native mySQL. The question does explicitly specify that it should not be.

Comment: Thanks for you replay. Any way to use this with Criteria ?

Answer (score 0):

SQL:

```
SELECT CAST(t.order AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS intOrder 
    FROM myTable t ORDER BY intOrder ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for you replay.  Any way to use this with Criteria ?